# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError on apache.poi libraries in Websphere App Server 8.5.5

Tags: java, websphere, war, ear

I'm encountering issues dealing with org.apache.poi libraries from this line `XSSFWorkbook wb_template = new XSSFWorkbook();`.
The initial error is `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTWorkbook.Factory`.

The application is deployed to Websphere Application Server 8.5.5 in it's own Application Server. It is built with Maven and the pom.xml includes :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have several environments with Websphere 8.5.5 installed and configured. The lower environment does not have these issues and the app works fine, but the higher environment is affected and this is cause for concern that this will happen in a live environment too.

I have tried adding the .jar libraries to /AppServer/lib directory, which had me add all `org.apache.poi` libraries and even `org.apache.common` as I tried to solve this error step by step, adding libraries which the app could not find. In the end I went full circle and got the `NoSuchFieldError` for `CTWorkbook.Factory` again.

I've activated **Class Loader Viewer** for the affected Application server and found that the difference between my environments is that, even though the library jars I'm having issues with are in the classpath, the Class Loader Viewer does not show these classes. Non `org.apache` classes are seen here as normal. The lower environment has these classes identified.

I'm looking for help to figure out why are the classes missing on runtime - the Websphere installations should be identical, the App Server configurations are identical, there are no changes to Class Loader settings in these App Servers.

Comment: Can you check your environment to see if there's more than one jar that contains either the openxml CTWorkbook class or whatever class is at the top of the stack (the one attempting to use the "missing" field)? If there is more than one jar that contains either of those classes, it's possible you're picking up the wrong one - sometimes the order of files within a directory that's put on a class path can vary between systems.

Comment: The Class Loader Viewer does not show any libraries that would use the CTWorkbook class. But the problem extends to more apache libs, for example, if I added the lib to AppServer/lib directory, the next error was `NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.collections4.ListValuedMap`.

Do you have a suggestion on how better I could search for jars in the environment?

Comment: I'd start by advising you not to put stuff in the server's /lib directory - that populates a server level extension class loader that is not intended for use by applications, and I'm not sure whether all its contents show up in the class loader viewer in the first place.

Comment: I'd suggest going back to your original configuration (before you put stuff in /lib but still got the NoSuchFieldError) and then enabling verbose class loading, which is a checkbox on the server JVM configuration panel in the admin console. That will add output to native_stderr.log that will tell you where every class in the JVM was loaded from, and you can check whether either CTWorkbook or its caller was loaded from somewhere unexpected.

Comment: Thanks for helping so far, Jarid. I have compared the output of native_stderr.log from both of my environments and to my suprise, they are mostly identical. The offending libraries both seem to be loading from my app package.
`class load: org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook from: file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/testCell/MyEAR.ear/MyWAR.war/WEB-INF/lib/poi-ooxml-5.2.0.jar` The exact class `CTWorkbook.Factory` is not in the log, as it should be under the poi libraries.
Do you have any more tips?

Comment: I'd suggest checking again, but this time just look for CTWorkbook - based on the format of the error message, I believe "CTWorkbook" is the name of the class, and "Factory" is the name of the field that's not being found (also, make sure you check the whole log in the event that there are multiple instances, not just settling on the first result). Also, if the class at the top of the stack is yours, I'd recommend taking a look at the source to check if there's a conditional reason why it might be referencing the Factory field, and whether that indicates something unexpected elsewhere.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I looked up that OpenXML API, and I think this is more likely a coding error in the code at the top of the stack - it looks like Factory is actually a Class, not a Field (which makes sense, given the capitalization). That means that the call leading to that error is referencing the Factory class incorrectly, in a way that the JVM sees as interacting with a field.